# Does the concept of Godhead (one God, but multiple persons) predate Christianity? Can we find evidence of this concept in Judaism before 0 A.D.?

Tags: history, trinity, origin, judaism, torah

Was the concept of Godhead (one God, but multiple persons) known by the Jews prior to the advent of Christianity? Were there Jews that held a Binitarian, Trinitarian or similar "Godhead" theology as a result of studying the Torah, long before Christianity came on the scene?

Comment: See [Were Jews in Jesus' day binitarian?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/68619/6071)

Comment: "In the beginning [...] the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters." (Genesis 1:1-2) I don't know offhand how Jews interpreted this, but Trinitarians often take this as referring to the persons of both the Father and the Holy Spirit. I believe there are other Trinitarian references in the OT, though I can't recall specific others offhand. (Also, same disclaimer; I can't actually answer your question.)